# Помогите со Switch-Case. Почему этот код не работает правильно?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script language="javascript">
var x = prompt("Enter a number: ");
b = x % 5;
switch(b) {
  case "1": {
    document.write("One!");
    break;
  }
  case "2": {
    document.write("Two!");
    break;
  }
  case "3": {
    document.write("Three!");
    break;
  }
  case "4": {
    document.write("Four!");
    break;
  }
  case "5": {
    document.write("Five!");
    break;
  }
  default: document.write("what??");
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Замените строковые литералы на числа, то есть вместо case "1": напишите case 1:

Comment: остаток от деления на 5 не может быть 5. Пропущен ноль.

Answer (score 3):

Предложение switch выполняет строгое сравнение на равенство (Strict Equality Comparison), то есть применяет оператор `===`  при котором типы операндов должны совпадать.

А потому замените все строковые литералы в `case` на целочисленные значения.

К тому же допустимые значения для остатка при делении на 5, если введенное число является целым, будут [0, 4].